# Location vs Content-Location on post requests

Tags: rest, http

I am confused about the header `Location` and `Content-Location`.

##### Content-Location

Regarding `Content-Location` I found this statement in the [spec](https://httpwg.org/specs/rfc7231.html#header.content-location). (Emphasis mine)

> For a state-changing request like PUT (Section 4.3.4) or POST (Section 4.3.3), it implies that the server's response contains the new representation of that resource, **thereby distinguishing it from representations that might only report about the action (e.g., "It worked!")**. This allows authoring applications to update their local copies without the need for a subsequent GET request.

However, in the mdn docs is an [example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Location#pointing_to_a_new_document_http_201_created) that shows the opposite behaviour.  (Emphasis mine)

> The site returns a **generic success message confirming the post was published**. The server specifies where the new post is with Content-Location:
>
> ```
> HTTP/1.1 201 Created
> Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
> Content-Location: /my-first-blog-post
>
> ✅ Success!
> ```

These two statements seem to contradict each other.

Now, I am unsure if I should use Content-Location for the case of **not** including the real entity in the response.

---

##### Location

The [spec](https://httpwg.org/specs/rfc7231.html#header.location) has a sentence about the `Location` header.

> For 201 (Created) responses, the Location value refers to the primary resource created by the request.

And mdn is [saying](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Location) the same.

> In cases of resource creation, it indicates the URL to the newly created resource.

---

I am confused which one to pick for a post response that does not include the entity.

I am guessing the `Location` header would be most appropriate for a generic post request where the entity can be viewed later. For example, posting a user and viewing it.

What about a POST response with a 202 code? For example, when posting a task to a queue where later only the status of the task can be viewed. So it isn't a real entity like a user. I.e. an email was dispatched to X clients based on the posted task, now I want to communicate where the status (PENDING, FAILURE or SUCCESS) can be viewed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct, and MDN is wrong about the first example. This example:

```
HTTP/1.1 201 Created
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Location: /my-first-blog-post

✅ Success!
```

Suggests that the contents of `/my-first-blog-post` *is* `✅ Success!`, due to the `Content-Location` header.

Given that you *don't* want to return the new resource's body, you should keep `Location` and omit `Content-Location`.

And if you have time: report the issue to the MDN maintainers.

> What about a POST response with a 202 code? For example, when posting a task to a queue where later only the status of the task can be viewed. So it isn't a real entity like a user. I.e. an email was dispatched to X clients based on the posted task, now I want to communicate where the status (PENDING, FAILURE or SUCCESS) can be viewed.

I would suggest a `Link` header.